# ASP.NET mobile website using remote database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

[image]

My scenario is as shown in the figure below. I have a database which is in the customer premises. It is connected to the a remote web server over the internet. I have to develop a mobile website which can manipulate data (insert, delete...etc) in this  database.

Which is the best way of doing this? Do I have to use webservices? (I have limited knowledge of webservices).

Comment: In the description you say mobile website, but in the diagram its a device, so does it need to be a website or can it be an application on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't *have* to use webservices.

This scenario's no different to the database server being hosted on your internal LAN - you simply address it in the connection string using a fully-qualified domain.

E.g.:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnection" connectionString="data source=sqlserver101.databasehost.com;user id=admin;password=admin;initial catalog=myDatabase;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
</connectionStrings>
```

The only difference is that you need to be a little more security-aware having a database server exposed to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

A web-service type of solution is the obvious choice, not necessarily what Microsoft calls web services though (i.e .Net Web Services) you simply need a way to send data in and out from the  web server, a way which the mobile device can support. You should look at the technique that is used to connect the customer premises to the web server, maybe that can be re-used. I am doing something similar with WCF [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)